# Question about the upper limit of a sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. I would like to show that $~lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}sup~p_n = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}sup_{m \geq n} \{p_m\}$. But I am unclear on what is meant by the right hand side of the equation. If someone knows and can explain it, that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Definition: $~lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}sup~p_n$ is the supremum of the set of all subsequential limits of $\{p_n\}$.

Comment: Thats the definition of $\limsup$..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently understood this for the first time and it helped me to pick numbers for n to visualize what is going on in the $ \sup_{m \geq n}p_m$ portion.  So let's do that:

for $n = 1$: $\sup_{m \geq 1}p_m = \sup\{ p_1,p_2,p_3,...\}$ or the supremum of all the $p_i$'s.

for $n = 2$: $\sup_{m \geq 2}p_m = \sup\{ p_2,p_3,p_4,...\}$ or the supremum of all the $p_i$'s after removing the first one.

so for $n = k$:$\sup_{m \geq k}p_m = \sup\{ p_k,p_{k+1},p_{k+2},...\}$ or the supremum of all the $p_i$'s after removing the first $k-1$ terms.

Now we take the limit of this process as $n \to \infty$. Hope this clarifies a bit. It should be relatively simple to see how the two sides are equivalent from this point.